# ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView - ERROR

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to customize my listview in Android like

[image: this]

What I am exactly trying to achieve is I want to add those color at the left side of each listview item and of course I want to use a different color for every item. How can I achieve this ?

This is the code where my listview is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:visibility="gone" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="500dp" >
    </ListView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Compute admission chance"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
        android:layout_below="@id/listView1"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
This is what I did for my listview item:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_layout,listRecNames);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:divider="?android:dividerVertical"
    android:showDividers="middle" >
    <!-- You can use any view here. Set background "rectangle.xml" drawable to this view.-->
    <View
        android:layout_width="20dip"
        android:layout_height="20dip"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/custom_spinner"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

but I get this error:

> ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView

Comment: What had you tried so far? Where did you failed?

Comment: Add that view in xml file of your listview item.

Comment: You need to use combination of CollapsingToolbarLayout and RecyclerView..

Comment: Go for recyclerView and create adapter for recycler view with custom xml file.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: https://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/

Comment: http://tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/11/android-collapsingtoolbarlayout-example_7.html

Comment: Nothing helped?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom implementation of `ArrayAdapter` where you implement the `getView()` to inflate your `View` and do exactly what you want.

What you have used is a generic adapter that works for list items that have just one text to display in a list with `TextView`s.

For more information, you may refer a tutorial like: [Custom ArrayAdapters](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#user-content-using-a-custom-arrayadapter)

Answer (score 0):

The Array adapter requires the id of the Textview to bind the value into list view.

```
  ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.spinner_layout,R.id.custom_spinner,listRecNames);
  lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```